# Gatling with GRPC setup, guide and more?

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling

hope you have a good day today.

I am a new user to both Gatling and GRPC, trying to set up a demo for investigating.

Firstly, this is my set up for akka-grpc build.sbt file:

```
name := "akka-grpc-quickstart-scala"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val akkaVersion = "2.8.4"
lazy val akkaHttpVersion = "10.5.2"
lazy val akkaGrpcVersion = "2.3.4"

enablePlugins(AkkaGrpcPlugin)

fork := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http2-support" % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-discovery" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-pki" % akkaVersion,

  // The Akka HTTP overwrites are required because Akka-gRPC depends on 10.1.x
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http2-support" % akkaHttpVersion,

  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",

  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion % Test,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % akkaVersion % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.1" % Test
)

enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
libraryDependencies += "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.9.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "io.gatling"            % "gatling-test-framework"    % "3.9.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.9.5" % "test",
  "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.9.5" % "test",
  "com.github.phisgr" % "gatling-grpc" % "0.16.0" % "test"
)
```

Then I put this in my plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.akka.grpc" % "sbt-akka-grpc" % "2.3.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-javaagent" % "0.1.5")

addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "4.5.0")
```

So I have 3 questions that comes up during the setup:

1/ When I run "sbt compile", project will show the .proto file BUT it is not in src/main/ or src/test/ directory, I have to copy and paste the file into it. Is this the right behavior of sbt ?

2/ I have tried to run the code of phisGr on the hub, however the project is in IntelliJ IDE (for now I'm using VSCode and can't change it) so I would like to ask for a simple Gatling script, with the akka-grpc demo run (the grpc demo run fine - only need gatling implement example).

3/ Will there be an update OR more documents on GRPC - Gatling ? Because there are not much on Internet. The current ones kind of lacking lots of information.

Thank you for reading.

Tried lots of example.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run "sbt compile", project will show the .proto file BUT it is not in src/main/ or src/test/ directory, I have to copy and paste the file into it. Is this the right behavior of sbt ?

I can't tell what file is in what directory from your description. My guess is that you're talking about the generated Scala code. They are a compilation result from the `.proto` files, so they live inside the `target` directory.
sbt should compile them to `.class`es with no problem.
Whether your IDE is smart enough to index the generated source code is another matter.

> I have tried to run the code of phisGr on the hub, however the project is in IntelliJ IDE (for now I'm using VSCode and can't change it) so I would like to ask for a simple Gatling script, with the akka-grpc demo run (the grpc demo run fine - only need gatling implement example).

The library being developed with IntelliJ has nothing to do how you use it. If you want, you can go without an IDE and use a simple text editor and run `sbt` from the command line.

Here's a demo of Gatling-gRPC;
https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc-sbt-demo

Here's a walk through of using Gatling-gRPC on an Akka gRPC server, easily found on google.
https://alexromanov.github.io/2021/08/23/gatling-grpc/

---

If you're not familiar with sbt, why pick the Scala stuff? You can use Gatling and gPRC with Gradle/Maven and Java/Kotlin.

Comment: Alexromanov guide is outdated. Compiling it just results in full of errors. My project demands to use Scala/sbt which I have no choice but to look into it, I also don't like to use a non-native Grpc support too.

Comment: No one can help unless you give the specific errors you got.

Comment: I have in total 5 errors which are on your library:
(channelBuilder: io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder[_])com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.StaticGrpcProtocol cannot be applied to (String)

io.gatling.core.check.FindCheckBuilder' is missing from the classpath. This symbol is required by 'value com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.check.GrpcCheckSupport.findCheckBuilder'. Make sure that type FindCheckBuilder is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`. A full rebuild may help

Comment: there are 3 more but I don't think I should bring that on now