# Symbol 'type io.gatling.core.check.FindCheckBuilder' is missing from the classpath

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling, scala-gatling, akka-grpc

I tried to implement gatling with Grpc as the following script, by phiSgr:

```
package load

import com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.Predef._
import example.myapp.helloworld.grpc.hello_world.{GreeterServiceGrpc, HelloRequest}
import io.gatling.core.Predef.{stringToExpression => _, _}
import io.grpc.Status
import load.Constants.grpcPsgConf
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.postfixOps

class GrpcSimulation extends Simulation {

  val scn = scenario("Make Hello Request and Get Response")
    .exec(grpc("Hello Request")
      .rpc(GreeterServiceGrpc.METHOD_SAY_HELLO)
      .payload(HelloRequest("Gatling Load Test"))
      .extract(_.message.some)(_ saveAs "message")
      .check(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
    )
    .exec(grpc("Hello Request with parameter from session")
      .rpc(GreeterServiceGrpc.METHOD_SAY_HELLO)
      .payload(session => HelloRequest(session.attributes("message").asInstanceOf[String]))
      .check(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
    )

  setUp(scn.inject(rampUsersPerSec(1) to (2) during (20 seconds)).protocols(grpcPsgConf.shareChannel))
}
```

When I run *sbt compile* it can be done successfully, however when I use *sbt "Gatling / testOnly *.GrpcSimulation"* it will return me these 2 errors:

```
[error] C:\Users\TriNP\Desktop\gatlingGrpc\gatling-grpc-tests-sample\src\test\scala\load\BiDiStreamingSimulation.scala:16:23: Symbol 'type io.gatling.core.check.FindCheckBuilder' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'value com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.check.GrpcCheckSupport.findCheckBuilder'.
[error] Make sure that type FindCheckBuilder is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'GrpcCheckSupport.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of io.gatling.core.check.
[error]   val bidiCall = grpc("BiDi call").bidiStream("bidi")
[error]                       ^
[error] C:\Users\TriNP\Desktop\gatlingGrpc\gatling-grpc-tests-sample\src\test\scala\load\GrpcSimulation.scala:20:28: Symbol 'type io.gatling.core.check.FindCheckBuilder' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'value com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.CallDefinition.ts'.
[error] Make sure that type FindCheckBuilder is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'CallDefinition.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of io.gatling.core.check.
[error]       .payload(HelloRequest("Gatling Load Test"))
[error]                            ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 09:20:29, 25 thg 9, 2023
sbt:gatling-grpc-tests-sample> reload
[info] welcome to sbt 1.9.6 (Oracle Corporation Java 17.0.8)
[info] loading settings for project gatling-grpc-tests-sample-build from assembly.sbt,gatling.sbt,plugins.sbt,scalapb.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from C:\Users\TriNP\Desktop\gatlingGrpc\gatling-grpc-tests-sample\project
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\TriNP\Desktop\gatlingGrpc\gatling-grpc-tests-sample\project\target\scala-2.12\sbt-1.0\classes ...
[error] C:\Users\TriNP\Desktop\gatlingGrpc\gatling-grpc-tests-sample\project\Dependencies.scala:2:11: object gatling is not a member of package sbt.io
[error] import io.gatling.core.Predef._
[error]           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

the build.sbt I'm using:

```
import Dependencies._

name := "gatling-grpc-tests-sample"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.12"

libraryDependencies ++=  gatlingDependencies ++ loggingDependencies ++ grpcDependencies ++
  Seq(
    "com.github.daddykotex" %% "courier" % "3.0.0-M2a",
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.4.1",
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "30.1.1-jre",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.6.10",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-protobuf-v3" % "2.6.10",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.10"
  )

enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)

PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (Compile / sourceManaged).value / "scalapb"
)
```

gatling.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "4.5.0")
```

plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.akka.grpc" % "sbt-akka-grpc" % "1.1.1")
```

scalapb.sbt"

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "1.0.0")

libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.10.10"
```

How do I fix this issue and can someone explain me the root cause ? any help would be appreciated.

Change the gatling and sbt version to match with current using.

Comment: Already answered your double post on Gatling's community forum: https://community.gatling.io/t/symbol-type-io-gatling-core-check-findcheckbuilder-is-missing-from-the-classpath/8321/3

Comment: as stated by @StéphaneLANDELLE before and asked PhisGr aka George Leung on Github, the problem is in the dependencies conflict. HOWEVER, I have stated that I used gatling-grpc v.0.16.0 and gatling 3.9.5, still got this error

Comment: You should also include `Dependencies.scala` in this question, as your `build.sbt` refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously incompatible dependency versions.

In the comment OP said

> HOWEVER, I have stated that I used gatling-grpc v.0.16.0 and gatling 3.9.5, still got this error"

A possible cause is that the versions are changed, but the build tool is still using the old version.

And in this error log, we can see why.

```
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\TriNP\Desktop\gatlingGrpc\gatling-grpc-tests-sample\project\target\scala-2.12\sbt-1.0\classes ...
[error] C:\Users\TriNP\Desktop\gatlingGrpc\gatling-grpc-tests-sample\project\Dependencies.scala:2:11: object gatling is not a member of package sbt.io
[error] import io.gatling.core.Predef._
[error]           ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

For some reason OP added `import io.gatling.core.Predef._`, an import line for the test code, to a file of the build script - `project/Dependencies.scala`. And this error prevented sbt from reloading and getting correct the dependency versions.

---

Once again, as I have noted in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155404/gatling-with-grpc-setup-guide-and-more/77160366#77160366), one doesn't have to use `sbt` or write Scala to use Gatling. And given OP's confusion, they should stick with more mainstream tools like Gradle/Maven.